# Hosting multiple Facebook apps on one domain using EV SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl

I would like to run multiple apps on Facebook under the one domain and also using EV SSL and needed to know if that is supported by Facebook to use one domain IE domain.com/fb-app/app1 domain.com/fb-app/app2 and so on. And does it matter if using EV SSL than just the standard SSL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course you can have multiple apps running on one domain. And your SSL certificate has to be accepted by browsers if you want to embed your apps into facebook.com.

Comment: Thanks mate, I wasn't sure about the domain part ( only new to Facebook apps ) As long as the EV SSL is accepted it would not matter being a EV SSL vs SSL